# Kiel oni parolas "Teal" en esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I cannot find the translation. I've looked on lernu.net/vortaro and https://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-esperanto/teal. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Do you mean to color teal or one of the many duck species called "teal" or something yet else? Please [edit] your question to specify.

Answer (score 4):

In [John Wells’ dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) there is this:

> **teal** kreko; bluverda

*Kreko* is a type of [duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_teal) called *teal* in English. The name of the colour comes from that.

*Bluverda* is the suggestion for the name of the colour in Esperanto.

Comment: For instance also German calls it _blaugrün_ (blue green). To differentiate between other colour names, _kreka bluverda_ could be used for the web colour _teal_.

Answer (score -1):

Mi proponas [turkisa](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkisa) aǔ turkiskolora por la koloro *teal*.

Comment: Pri la angla vorto "teal" vidu  la komentojn sub [tia artikolo](https://www.newelementary.com/2017/07/bricktastic-colourtastic-part-4.html) kaj ankaǔ la koloron en la bildoj.

Comment: Laŭ tiu artikolo, esence estus "helturkisa". Eble aldonu elementojn el la artikolo al via afiŝo por ke ĝi ne tute malaperu...

Comment: La koloro `teal` estas parto de oficiala listo de kolornomoj, ankaŭ kun turkisa (turquoise). Do evitinda. https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/

Comment: Ĉu jen oficiala listo de html-kolornomoj en Esperanto?